# Routing certain Internet traffic through browser based VPN or private browser like Epic

Tags: networking, security, vpn, browser, privacy

There are some free VPNs that only secure browser traffic (so not really a VPN but they say they are a VPN, it's just semantics), but that do not secure traffic from other programs. As of right now, I just want to know how to do this, or if it is possible and I don't have a specific task at hand. For right now, maybe mail or one drive?

There are also private browsers like Epic that, to the best of my knowledge, keep my information secure, private and anonymous and I would not mind using this as an alternative to routing my traffic through a browser based VPN. Anyone know how to do this stuff?

Comment: "There are some free VPNs that only secure browser traffic, but that do not secure traffic from other programs". This is a ridiculous statement, if a service says this, then they are not a vpn .  Any event, your question, isn't clear

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing VPNs and proxies.

VPNs (virtual private networks) provides IP routing and usually set routes in your operating system so that your traffic (or some part of it, based on the IP you are sending data to) goes through it.

Proxies are protocol dependent (HTTP(S) in this case) and require an application to send all it traffic to a specific IP and port to be used.

I believe Epic to use proxies. And it allows you to prevent your ISP to spy on your traffic by allowing theirs to do exactly the same (but maybe with the knowledge that Epic users might use it for things they want to hide, including illegal ones). (Obviously wanting to hide something does not mean it is illegal, but the contrary often holds.)

Comment: I know the difference between the two, but if I am not mistaken, with regards to privacy they are pretty similar. I hide my IP and my connection is encrypted, so if someone wants to trace any of my activity back to me they will have significant difficulty. I know this sounds kind of sketchy ;), trying to be all anonymous, but right now I really do not plan on doing anything, I am just curious if it is possible and how to do it, maybe then I could improve my own personal security and privacy.